# setInterval() issue in Mozilla (Javascript function)

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I'm running through JavaScript: the Definitive Guide
It offers up the following code to explain setTimeout() and setInterval(), and my issue is that it runs in Safari without issue
but in Mozilla it doesn't seem to trigger at all, anyone have any
thoughts?

> The issue is in the following function:

```
function invoke(f,start,interval,end){
        if(!start) start=0; //default to 0ms (start right away)
        if (arguments.length <= 2)
            setTimeout(f,start);
```

> It functions if I don't set the inverval and end, but if I do
>   something goes janky

```
    else{
        setTimeout(repeat,start);
        function repeat(){
        var h = setInterval(f,interval);
        //if(end)setTimeout(function(){clearInterval(h)},end);
        }
    }
    }
```

> This is just the dummy function that runs on setTimeout() and
>   setInterval()

```
    function f(){
    if(true)
        alert("yo");
    }



<button onclick="invoke('f,200,1000,5000')">yo</button>
```

Hopfully somone has some insight into this one, thanks.

Comment: What actually happens when you run it with the interval?  `janky` isn't a very descriptive term and last I looked wasn't in my programming dictionary.  Did you try it without a blocking alert?  Try using just a console.log() instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gsfyy/2/)  this now appear to work,

as the others have said you need to remove the 's arround your parameter to invoke

also FireBug for firefox ( get it if you dont already ) fails with Repeat is undefined so I've also modified that a little too.

Answer (score 1):

```
<button onclick="invoke('f,200,1000,5000')">yo</button>
```

should be

```
<button onclick="invoke(f,200,1000,5000)">yo</button>
```

Otherwise you are passing the string 'f,200,1000,5000' as the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're passing a single variable to your `invoke` function due to the placement of your second single quote.  Try changing it to

`<button onclick="invoke('f',200,1000,5000)">yo</button>`

and see if that works any better.